# C# ASPX FTP Filesize wrong after upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ftpwebrequest

I am uploading a file through FTP that is 613.6 kb, it is a PDF file.  When it arrives on the server it is now 82 KB.

in my Web.Config I have

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="7200" maxRequestLength="2097151" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

my Code is this

```
 void UploadFileToFtp(FileInfo file, FtpWebRequest req)
    {
        int buffLength = 2048;

        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file.OpenRead(), Encoding.Default))

        {
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                while (reader.PeekChar() > 0) writer.Write(reader.ReadBytes(buffLength));
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
            }
            reader.Close();
        }

    }
```

I thought it had something to do with the Encoding so I tried ASCII, Default and Unicode none of which made a diffrence.  I added the Flush and the Close thinking that was doing it, but no help either.  I was getting an error regarding the encoding and once I added that the error went away, but I have no other errors.

Comment: Is the 82 kb file corrupt, or can you still open it?

Comment: corrupt, adobe will not opne it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be that the file contains zeros and your comparison should be `reader.PeekChar() >=0` rather than `reader.PeekChar() > 0`?

Comment: And? PDF files can contain bytes of value 0x00.

Comment: This well might be the issue. Charcode `0` is a valid character that may be present in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader`, they are likely doing some kind of buffering I am not convinced you need that. Try this code and see what happens

```
var buffer = new byte[2048];
int bytesRead = 0;
var reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();

using (var fs = file.OpenRead())
{
    while (0 < (bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)))
        reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```